# Create a lag/laged variable based on a date rather than row number with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

Supouse one has a panel data similar to the following, (*e.x.*) with two variables "`dates`" and "`sales`":

```
  set.seed(123)
  df <- data.frame(
  "dates" = c(as.Date("2021-01-01")+0:30,
              as.Date("2022-01-01")+0:30),
  "sales" = 0:61+(sample(1:30,62,replace = T)))
```

**Notice:**

- It is daily data from just January of 2021 and 2022, therefore there
  is a time gap since data form in between dates is not available.
- You want to create  (for example) two lagged variables:

  - I) one day lag: the "sales" from the previous date
  - II) one year lag: the "sales" from the same day one year before
- You want to do this in "one-shot", I meant, in a line of code using pipes ("`%>%`")
- The solution must be a generalized one: For example, if one wants later to create a "one month lag" or a "45 days lag", etc...

**My attempts so far:**

***1st Try**:*

I've been trying to use dplyr's function "`lag()`", but the problem is that it creates a lag but based on the row number rather than the date in "`dates`". So it works well but when having time continuos datasets, but not with discontinuous ones:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(lag_1day = lag(sales,order_by = dates,1))
```

See that despite that all continuos dates are fine, when it reaches the discontinuity, it assigns the last day by row and not by date, therefore assigning a value instead of a "`NA`"

```
> df[30:34,]
        dates sales lag_1day
30 2021-01-30    52       58
31 2021-01-31    34       52
32 2022-01-01    55       34
33 2022-01-02    60       55
34 2022-01-03    36       60
```

***2nd Try:***

Another way I've been using is by creating a copy of the first data frame, then adding to "`dates`" the required amount of days for the lag, and finally merging both data frames. It works perfectly (the outcome is the desired result), but I think is not efficient since is not a "one-shot" solution, and it's creating another data frame.

```
df <- merge(
  df,(df %>% 
        mutate(dates = dates+1) %>% 
        rename(lag_1day = sales)), 
  by = "dates", all.x = T)


> df[30:34,]
        dates sales lag_1day
30 2021-01-30    59       37
31 2021-01-31    49       59
32 2022-01-01    35       NA
33 2022-01-02    46       35
34 2022-01-03    50       46
```

Comment: If you're working with time-based data, you should use packages/functions designed to be sensitive to dates, such as `xts` or `tsibble`. Otherwise you're trying to build a bunch of guardrails yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could try using if_else inside the mutate. It looks less clean, and not really efficient timewise, as it would need to make n comparisons to get the answer, but it would be just one pipe.

Not sure about the exact functions but in pseudocode

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(lag_1day = 
             ifelse(lag(date,1))+1== date), 
                    lag(sales,1), 
                    NA)
```